# ODBC Driver in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, database, odbc

Researching writing an ODBC driver for a particular data source. Since I am most familiar with .Net, was curious if it would be possible to do part (or most) of the coding in .Net... presumeably with a shim dll that would call it via interop. If this is possible, I am then curious if some source code exists that already does this, and might provide a good starting point for my project?

Comment: ODBC drivers are written in C.  The api is entirely C based and will be used by client code that is written in native code.  Even in .NET, System.Data.Odbc uses pinvoke to talk to the driver.  This makes trying to write a driver in managed code a perilous adventure.

Comment: I understand this, but if I have data in a .Net application which I wish to expose through an odbc interface- then interop/pinvoke away but it should be doable.

Comment: This touches on the subject http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/515106-implementing-odbc-driver-database-written-c

Comment: Check out http://www.simba.com/drivers/simba-engine-sdk/ which provides an SDK for building out ODBC drivers, and provides an API allowing you to build in .NET if you so choose. (Disclosure: I work for Simba)